# Icon is loaded, but not shown (html, css)

Tags: html, css, icons

I have an icon which is actually on my webpage but I still cant see it.

HTML

```
<i class="iconMan"></i>
```

CSS

```
.iconMan{
    background-image: url(../../assets/imgs/iconMan.png);
    display: block;
  }
```

this is what I get:

[image]

The Icon should be next to "Test User" but it's not showing. I already tried adjusting height and width but it didn't work.
Any suggestions what I could do?

Comment: are you sure the path to your image is correct? Try giving it a fixed width and height and setting the background position to center and the background size to contain. A screenshot of the console would be nice to see the rendered styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for displaying an icon you can move your styling to the `::after` or `::before` pseudo selectors.

```
.iconMan {
    display: inline-block;
}

.iconMan::before {
    content: url(../../assets/imgs/iconMan.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed quotes

```
.iconMan{
    background-image: url("../../assets/imgs/iconMan.png");
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: quotes are optional for URLs here. https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/

Comment: I also tried this, but I dont think that this is the problem. It's also possible without quotes and my icon is actually loaded (I checked the network tab in developer tools and I get a 200 back)

Answer (score -1):

try to do like this

```
<img src="/assets/imgs/iconMan.png"
```

I guess it will work 
just put this to your html code

Comment: Can you elaborate your question: what do you want to achieve and what is not working? And it is best to add a MWE that others can compile in order to see your problem and easily propose solutions.